# grpc-java async call in ServerInterceptor

Tags: java, asynchronous, authorization, interceptor, grpc

I have a grpc-java server and need to make an async call to an auth service, before processing a request. I think this should be done in an interceptor, but it requires to synchronously return a Listener from interceptCall()

```
class AuthInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
        ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
        Metadata headers,
        ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next
    ) {
        String token = ""; //get token from headers
        authService.authorize(token).subscribe(
            ok -> // process the request
            error -> call.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED, headers)
        );
        // Here we need to return a Listener, but we haven't started a call yet
    }
}
```

So the questions are: how to make an async call from a ServerInterceptor, and if it can't be done, what is the right way to asynchronously authenticate requests it grpc? I know it can be done directly in grpc services with StreamObservers, but request authorization is a cross cutting concern and interceptors seem to be a perfect place for it.

Comment: Can you update your question showing what you ended up with using the `DelayedListener`? It's unclear to me how to connect the dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need to return a `ServerCall.Listener`. But since you don't know the `Listener` to delegate to, you can override each method in the `Listener` to add the callback to a queue. Once the authentication is complete, drain the queue.

```
class DelayedListener<ReqT> extends Listener<ReqT> {
  private Listener<ReqT> delegate;
  private List<Runnable> events = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

  @Override public synchronized void onMessage(ReqT message) {
    if (delegate == null) {
      events.add(() -> delegate.onMessage(message));
    } else {
      delegate.onMessage(message);
    }
  }
  ...
  public synchronized void setDelegate(Listener<ReqT> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    for (Runnable runnable : events) {
      runnable.run();
    }
    events = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Would it work with ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of synchronization on the callbacks and setDelegate()?

Comment: your solution works great and solves the general problem. I've found another possible solution: it seems that a `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` that forwards all callbacks as usual and only delays the `onHalfClosed()` callback, also works for me. Or this solution has threading problems?

Comment: You need to make sure to "drain" all queued events before directly forwarding new events. If you _just_ used ConcurrentLinkedQueue + volatile delegate, then you have one of two races: 1) `this.delegate = delegate` is at the beginning of `setDelegate()` and lets new events "race" before older events, or 2) `this.delegate = delegate` is at the end of `setDelegate()` and events could get "stuck" in the queue. You really need a lock when queuing. It is possible to avoid the lock if `delegate != null` and when calling `runnable.run()`, but it is more complex. See DelayedStream in grpc

Comment: It is true that the stub for unary and server-streaming calls delay calling the application until `onHalfClosed()`. However, 1) other interceptors will still run, 2) it isn't true for client-streaming and bidi-streaming, and 3) there are some alternative server stubs floating around in the ecosystem and they may not behave the same way.

Comment: I think I can live with the simpler solution at least for now: we only have unary calls, and we control both the server and the client, so there're no alternative implementations. Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: It's not clear to me how does the `DelayedListener`work. Do we return it without setting the delegate, and `authorize` callback calls `setDelegate` with `serverCallHandler.startCall(call, headers)`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, yes. It queues while waiting for authorize to complete and then then you drain the queue with setDelegate().

Comment: @EricAnderson If `serverCallHandler.startCall` is not called until auth callback, listener `onMessage` still gets called? On the surface, it seems like until the call is started, `onMessage` shouldn't get called.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, the call is started as soon as the interceptor is called. That said, the call to onMessage() should natuarally be delayed until call.request() is called, but the idea is to buffer all callbacks and onMessage() was just an example.